# Solving Big Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I came through a question back some days. $$f(x)=x^8+5x^7+8x^6+13x^5+24x^4+8x^3+32x^2-12$$

How many solves are there for this, where $x$ is negative? How to solve this and other this types of questions?

Comment: You can try [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) for example to count number of negative roots

Comment: For a rough estimate, you can use Descatre's Rule of Sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Sturm's theorem, the polynomial has exactly two real roots, one negative and one positive. The negative one is $x= - 0.59679903383\cdots$